# Return type object methods

Tags: c++, class, methods, initialization

If I have this generic method, where a type `Foo` object is returned using parameters derived from `string s`:

```
Foo createFoo(string s)
{
    int index, first, second, third, fourth, fifth;

    Foo fooName(int first, int second,int third,int fourth,int fifth);
    return fooName;
}
```

And then in main, I try to do something like this:

```
Foo newFoo = createFoo(argv[2]);
```

Why does the compiler give me this error?

```
file.cc:30:1: error: ‘Foo’ does not name a type file.cc: In function
‘int main(int, char**)’: file.cc:180:38: error: ‘createFoo’ was not
declared in this scope
```

Coming from Java, doing something like this doesn't usually give me any problems, why would this be a problem in C++? How could I fix this?

Edit 1:
A few suggestions asked where my `Foo` class definition is located. It was located after the `createFoo` method so I moved the `createFoo` method after the `Foo` class definition segment of code and tried compiling.
Now a new error occurs:

```
file.cc: In function ‘Foo createFoo(std::string)’: file.cc:153:9:
error: conversion from ‘Foo (*)(int, int, int, int, int)’ to
non-scalar type ‘Foo’ requested
```

Comment: Are you #including `Foo`'s definition into your main source file?

Comment: Where did you define Foo? If it is after createFoo method, then take it before.

Comment: Foo's class definition is located in the same .cc file. In fact, everything is located in the same file, for now.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the header that defines "Foo", or you forgot to add a using directive to pull it in from the namespace where it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `return fooName;` is returning the function `fooName`, I think you intended to return the result of the function call, it should be something like `return fooName(first,  second, third, fourth, fifth);`

Answer (score 0):

Mert was right in questioning my method location. The method codeblock should have been located after the Foo class definition location within the file.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your second error, the conversion one:

```
Foo fooName(int first, int second,int third,int fourth,int fifth);
```

You intend to create new object instance, passing some parameters to the object constructor. But instead you end up declaring a new function. Remove type names (the "int"s) from parameters to fix this.

You should also be aware of [the most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).